# What is wrong with the way I'm establishing a PHP session?

Tags: php, session

I'm using the following code. Session is working on the same page; on the next page it is not showing the session variable value.  Please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['emailaddress']=$emailAddress;
    header("Location: $success "); /* Redirect browser */
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Are `$emailAddress` and `$success` in scope? You should show all of the code if you want help :)

Answer (score 0):

use `session_start()` in the page that you are redirecting to, as well (`$success`), before accessing the session values there

So that the "success.php" page looks something like:

```
<?
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(some_condition is true)
{
session_regenerate_id();
session_start();
$_SESSION['emailaddress']=$emailAddress;
header("location: member-index.php");
exit();
}
```

### on secure page:

```
<?php
//Start session
session_start();
//Check whether the session variable is present or not
       if(!$_SESSION['emailAddress']) 
        {
        header("location: access-denied.php");
        exit();
    }
?>

<p>This is secured page with session: <b><?php echo $_SESSION['emailAddress']; ?></b>
```